# I am trying to handle exceptions in my login page but its not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to handle exceptions in my `LoginView` but its not working (It does not print it out to the user in the dialogue box. I don't know if I am missing something).

This is where I am trying to implement the exceptions in my `LoginView`.

```
 Future loginCatch() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _email.text.trim(),
        password: _password.text.trim(),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return const AlertDialog(
              content: Text('User not found'),
            );
          },
        );
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('wrong password');
      }
      ;
    }
  }
```

This is my `LoginView`:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:thehunt/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:thehunt/views/forgot_password_view.dart';

class LoginView extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback showRegisterView;
  const LoginView({super.key, required this.showRegisterView});

  @override
  State<LoginView> createState() => _LoginViewState();
}

class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  //text controllers
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;

  Future logIn() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _email.text.trim(),
      password: _password.text.trim(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future loginCatch() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _email.text.trim(),
        password: _password.text.trim(),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return const AlertDialog(
              content: Text('User not found'),
            );
          },
        );
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('wrong password');
      }
      ;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Welcome to The Hunt',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 36),

                //email field

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Enter your email here',
                        ),
                        controller: _email,
                        enableSuggestions: false,
                        autocorrect: false,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10),

                //password field

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Enter your password ',
                        ),
                        controller: _password,
                        obscureText: true,
                        enableSuggestions: false,
                        autocorrect: false,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 10),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) {
                                return ForgotPasswordView();
                              },
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Forgot your password?',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                //login button

                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 25.0,
                  ),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: logIn,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Login',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 36),

                // register now

                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      //onTap: widget.showRegisterPage,
                      child: Text(
                        'Not registered yet?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: widget.showRegisterView,
                      child: Text(
                        ' Register now',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )

                // TextButton(
                //   onPressed: () {
                //     Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                //       registerRoute,
                //       (route) => false,
                //     );
                //   },
                //   child: const Text('Not registered yet? Register here'),
                // )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please could someone show me how to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? is do you get any erorrs?

Comment: It does not print it out to the user in the dialogue box. I don't know if I am missing something

Comment: The code is there but does not function yet

Comment: You're calling logIn, not loginCatch.  You have no error handling yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _email.text.trim(),
    password: _password.text.trim(),
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return const AlertDialog(
        content: Text(e.toString().split("] ")[1]),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: the part where it says content: Text(e.toString().split("] ")[1]), gives me an error. please can you recheck it again?

Comment: @CarltonS can you share the error?